# Android Bluetooth Discovery Only Devices using my App

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-device-discovery

Is possible to limit the results of a startDiscovery()  ? Giving as results only clients that are also using my app ? In my App users can be servers or clients..
I am not asking for code, I just want to know if its possible and then maybe aim me to the right method.
Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it may not be possible to limit the bluetooth search but yes it is possible to connect to a device using your android application that is possible through making a connection through the   secure socket using the UUID. for more refer to [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html)!